# How to Retrieve consent status for Forward to the Google Mobile Ads SDK in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sdk, admob, gdprconsentform, ump

I have Implemented my app to load consent form for EU economic aria users. Message is displaying correctly. Users can select "do not consent" or "consent" options from that.

[image]

But I see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/eu-consent) they are mentioning If a user has consented to receive only non-personalized ads, we need to configure an AdRequest object with the following code to specify that only non-personalized ads should be requested:

```
final AdRequest = AdRequest(nonPersonalizedAds: true);
```

But how can we retrieve user selected consent status for forward
to the AdRequest.

I am using google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0 to display ads and also the consent form.
Is any way to get selected consent status or save selected status in a shared preferences when user click on the button in consent form.

this is the class created by me to load consent form

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class ConsentUpdate
{

  ///Function use to request the latest consent Information---------------------
  requestLatestConsentInformation()
  {

    final params = ConsentRequestParameters(
      consentDebugSettings: ConsentDebugSettings(
        debugGeography: DebugGeography.debugGeographyEea,
        testIdentifiers: ["EDA1C0CE59EF80A7C949F6B128CC96D9"]
      )
    );

    ConsentInformation.instance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
      params,
      () async
      {
        // The consent information state was updated.
        // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
        if (await ConsentInformation.instance.isConsentFormAvailable())
        {
          loadForm();
        }

      },
      (FormError error)
      {
        // Handle the error
      },
    );
  }
  ///End of function use to request the latest consent information--------------


  ///Function use to load the form----------------------------------------------
  void loadForm()
  {
    ConsentForm.loadConsentForm(
          (ConsentForm consentForm) async
          {
             // Present the form
            var status = await ConsentInformation.instance.getConsentStatus();

            if (status == ConsentStatus.required)
            {
              consentForm.show((formError)
              {
                loadForm(); // Handle dismissal by reloading form
              });
            }

          },
          (FormError formError)
          {
            // Handle the error
          },
    );
  }
  ///End of function use to load the form---------------------------------------


  ///Function use to update consent information---------------------------------
  updateConsentInformation()
  {

      ConsentInformation.instance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
        ConsentRequestParameters(),
        () async
      {

        if(await ConsentInformation.instance.isConsentFormAvailable())
        {
          ConsentForm.loadConsentForm((consentForm)
          {
            consentForm.show((formError) async
            {

            });
          },
          (formError)
          {

          }
          );
      }

    },
    (error)
    {

    }
    );

  }
  ///End of function use to update consent information--------------------------


}
```

Comment: Hello friend, did you manage to solve this problem?